# Boost out-of-tree build

Tags: boost, b2

Boost still uses its very own crazy build system called `b2`. Since nobody else uses it, they include a script to build `b2` before you build Boost itself: `./bootstrap.sh`.

If you run this from another directory it does build `b2` elsewhere, but somehow you still get some binary files in

```
tools/build/src/engine/bootstrap/
```

Is there any way to get a completely clean build of Boost?

Comment: Could you do a fresh clone from github and see if there's a CMakeLists.txt in the library you need?

Comment: There's been a big push within Boost to deprecate b2 and use CMake, so you might win on the develop branch.

Comment: Astonishing that such a primitive, rudimentary feature is still impossible in boost.